# Parity : Recover from phrase bugged?

Tags: parity, recovery

Testing it out :

Creating new account via "Create new account manually", it shows the phrase in the end, copy it to txt.

Deleting `Account1`, Creating new account via "Recover from phrase" - pasting the phrase = it created a different `Account2` with different address.

Now, I can delete and re-create `Account2` with this phrase, but not `Account1`.

Whats the deal here?