# can parity recovery phrases still be used?

Tags: parity, recovery, parity-wallet

I have a wallet generated by an old version of parity such that it gave me a recovery phrase, since I have  forgotten the password.  (I think I know the password, but parity disagrees with me).

How do I use the recovery phrase to re-gain access to the wallet?  This must be documented somewhere.  I have tried to track this info down online, and found things like [this](https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/parity-phrases-no-longer-supported)  which make me nervous.  But I think that's another wallet service.  I also found [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10236/parity-recover-from-phrase-bugged).   which seems not to have been answered.

As for "Creating new account via "Recover from phrase"", this screenshot shows that I don't have such an option:

[image]

Comment: Go to ACCOUNTS > RESTORE. See https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Backing-up-&-Restoring :)

Comment: @5chdn   -thank you for the advice. that seems to be what I was looking for.  saw it earlier, and didn't recognize  it  for what  it was.  -however-, the original problem does not seem to have been solved.  in doing the recovery, I specified a new password.  I assume that this new password will be the one associated with the newly recovered account?  unfortunately, when I try to send ether from this account, using the new password, it still does not work.  can you clarify for me how the system is supposed to work please?

Comment: You have to remove the old account first.

Comment: @5chdn -ok, how do  I do that?  I have now tried deleting it, and it asks for the account password.  which is what I don't have.

Comment: Move the old keys out of `C:\Users\You\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\keys\ethereum` and start the wallet again.

Comment: @5chdn  -thank you!  this solution seems to have worked!  ..if you put it as an answer I'll accept it! :-)